# numpy array slicing: explicit/implicit copies and memory management

Tags: arrays, numpy

This is a beginner python question and has ultimately to do with memory management.

I am slicing an uint32 numpy array into 2 parts and then trying to create an uint8 view of one of the subarrays. Note that by creating a view, I mean re-interpreting the underlying data in memory in uint8, not casting the variable in uint8 : so the size changes in the process.

This is the inital array and an example of the view, works fine :

```
a=np.array([(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12)],np.int32)
a.view(np.int8) # everything is fine
```

This crashes (c is not a hard copy and still tied to the original array) :

```
a=np.array([(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12)],np.int32)
c, a= np.split (a,[1],1);
c.view(np.int8) #oups
```

Ditching the original array before creating the view doesn't help either :

```
a=np.array([(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12)],np.int32)
c, b= np.split (a,[1],1);
del a
c.view(np.int8) #oups
```

This is the best I came up with :

```
a=np.array([(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12)],np.int32)
c, a= np.split (a,[1],1);
c=np.copy(c).view(np.uint8) #ok, but really ?!?
```

Is there a better way to split an array into 2 subarrays so that numpy consider them "native", without copying them ? (of course the original array is then discarded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashes isn't the right term.  It just gives an error message:

```
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

And forget about 'discarding' the original; the split products are still around, and use the original data buffer.

If you had split the array along axis 0, the view would work.

```
In [368]: c0.view(np.int8)
Out[368]: array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Or if the original was `order='F'`:

```
In [369]: a=np.array([(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12)],np.int32,order='F')

In [370]: c,b=np.split(a,[1],1)

In [371]: c.view(np.int8)
Out[371]: 
array([[1],
       [0],
       ...
       [9],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=int8)
```

This last can be reshaped to (3,4) if needed.

It may help to visualize the layout of the numbers in the original data buffer

```
[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]
```

The view you are asking for is:

```
[ 1,0,0,0,  2,  3,  4,  5,0,0,0,  6,  7,  8,  9,0,0,0, 10, 11, 12]
```

It is happy to view the whole thing as `int8`, but not just bits and pieces.

With the alternatives you are asking to view contiguous blocks as bytes

```
[ 1,0,0,0,  2,0,0,0,  3,0,0,0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Ok I get it, my views ended up in discontinuous memory chunks. It means I'll have to transpose the array in memory sooner or later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

View `a` as dtype `np.int8` *before* spliting or slicing. Then you could use

```
In [219]: c, _ = np.split(a.view(np.int8), [4], 1)

In [220]: c
Out[220]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

or even simpler,

```
In [286]: c = a.view(np.int8)[:, :4]
In [287]: c
Out[287]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

instead.